# hot-update.json 404 (Not Found) triggered randomly when saving a file in a webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hmr

Randomly, when I save a file within my webpack project while running `webpack serve` (I work with Vscode and the automatic saving is activated), the HMR will throw me the error `hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)`.
This error will loop infinitely and the only way to temporarily solve the issue is to refresh the page.

Here's a screenshot of the error in the browser's console:
[HMR error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2myUT.png)

I searched a solution and found this topic: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1385
I tried everything, unsuccessfully.

Here's my repo: https://github.com/aymeric35/restaurant/tree/dev

The issue can be reproduced by editing a file in `src` and saving it while running `npm run start` or `npm webpack serve`, the error appears randomly so it's difficult to trigger it on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error happens when I run my Vue app on port `8080`.

If I run it on another port, for instance:

```
npm run serve -- --port 8085
```

the error doesn't appear